# Should a JSON-P callback function accept a string?

Tags: ajax, json, rest, callback, jsonp

I'm calling a REST API somebody else created.  It supports JSONP to facilitate cross domain access.

The response I get back from the service looks like:

```
mycallback('{"token": "123456789"}');
```

Notice the single quotes wrapping the JSON data; Passing it as a string rather than a raw object.  JQuery can handle this, but other libraries seem to expect a raw object instead.

```
mycallback({"token": "123456789"});
```

The raw object parameter makes more sense to me since it avoids the need to parse the JSON data, but I want to know for sure before asking the maintainer of the API to make the adjustment:

Which is most correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a javascript literal (second) as [shown here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is more correct as it avoids deserializing the string back to a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a string is obviously a bad thing - you have two choices (#1 is preferred):

1. Ask the developer of the JSONP service to send proper JSONp instead of a string
2. Make your callback function smart so it uses something like `payload = JSON.parse(payload);` in case `payload` is a string.

Comment: I'm using built in JSON-P handling in the framework I'm using so #2 isn't really possible/practical.